# How can I modify a process variable using Powershell in a Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Tests step in my pipeline. I want that step to run all tests on scheduled runs but only impacted Tests on manual or gated runs.
To do this, I linked the `runOnlyImpactedTests` value to a process variable and I'm trying to modify its value using Powershell.

I'm able to read the variable but I can't change it. I have two questions but first, here are the PS scriptlet

```
Write-Host "a ${Env:Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests} b"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Parameters.runOnlyImpactedTests]True"
Write-Host "c ${Env:Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests} d"

#Build Reasons:
#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff736208(v=vs.120)

if($Env:BUILD_REASON -eq "Schedule"){
    Write-Host "Is Scheduled. Should run all tests"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Parameters.runOnlyImpactedTests]False"
}

#gci env:
#gci variable:

# Use the environment variables input below to pass secret variables to this script.
```

and its output

```
2019-11-04T18:32:37.5783531Z Génération du script.
2019-11-04T18:32:37.6377454Z a False b
2019-11-04T18:32:37.6408504Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\BuildsVnexAgents\Agt1-3348\_work\_temp\2fca26a4-3bb5-4d51-9d90-a29aa4c755b5.ps1'"
2019-11-04T18:32:37.9377454Z c False d
2019-11-04T18:32:37.9846229Z
```

I also tried setting the variable using `Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests` and `Env:Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests` but they all give the same result.

My two questions now:

1. Why isn't the variable taking the value
2. If it can't work that way, are there alternatives in achieving my goal?

Comment: You may want to try line #3 in next step. According to the documentation the value gets initialized after the task is completed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#expansion-of-variables

Comment: I was also working toward this information. What I found is that it works but not all the time. I tried using the exact same line in a script with comments at the top that failed and then without the comments and it worked. I event had to almost identical scripts, the only difference was in the YAML where the one not working had some spaces before the write-host command. But at least it  Please write this as an answer so I can award you your points.

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you?

```
${Env:Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests} = $false
Write-Host "a ${Env:Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests} b"
${Env:Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests} = $true
Write-Host "c ${Env:Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests} d"
```

**Output:**

```
2019-11-05T09:56:39.8505031Z a False b
2019-11-05T09:56:39.8513437Z c True d
```

`${Env:Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests}` should also avalible in other pipeline tasks.

Comment: I tried this and though some times in works (the value is changed in the next task), other times it doesn't. I also tried to change ProcParam_runOnlyImpactedTests and got the same result.
In all cases, no matter if the value was shown has modified or not, the Tests task does not use the value. Maybe I should cancel the question?

Comment: It's hard to give you a answer to that. For my experiance my example works. Do you use `Azure DevOps Service` or `Azure DevOps Server`? Do use a `Self-Hosted Agent`? My be we can answer 'If it can't work that way, are there alternatives in achieving my goal?'.

Answer (score 0):

Testing according to Fairoz's comment, it is true that when `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=Parameters.runOnlyImpactedTests]True"` is used in the script, the output of the value of this variable will not change in the same task. The modified value will be output normally in the subsequent task.

```
steps:  
    - powershell: 
        Write-Host " a $(Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests) a "
        "##vso[task.setvariable variable=Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests]True"
        Write-Host " b $(Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests) b "
    - powershell: Write-Host "c $(Parameters_runOnlyImpactedTests) c "
```

[image][image]